# Subset list of wave cycles(wave progressing from 0 -> positive peak -> 0 -> negative peak -> 0 ) from dataframe in R / Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

The data frame consists of a signal values which consists 1700+ observations. I need to **subset the values of each cycle into a list called `templates`**. Obviously the signal values that I am interested starts from  `0 -> reaches positive peak -> comes back to zero -> reaches negative peak -> comes back to zero again`, similar to sine wave.

Below is the sample dataframe
`df`

```
ID    S   S_lag
1    33   0
2    33   0
3    33   0
4    33   0
5    33   0
6    34   1
7    33  -1
8    33   0
9    34   1
10   34   0
11   34   0
12   34   0
13   35   1
14   41   6
15   52  11
16   70  18
17   72   2
18   73   1
19   74   1
20   74   0
21   75   1
22   86   1
23   84  -2
24   64  -20
25   43  -21
26   35  -8
25   31  -4
27   29  -2
28   27  -2
29   26  -1
30   26   0
```

Based on the above example dataframe my values of interest is from `ID 12` to `ID 30`. 
So as required `templates[1]` consists of first cycle values, `tepmlates[2]` consists of second cycle values and goes on.

The plot of my `S_lag` values are as below and my values of interest is within the red box.

NOTE: I need the corresponding values of `S` to be subset, not `S_lag` [image]